# Check all charts for data and hide ones that have none

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to check my graphs made with *highcharts* if they have any data on *load* and every *redraw* of the graph.

I made it work with this code:

```
(function (H) {

    var chartPrototype = H.Chart.prototype;

    // Hide graph if there are no data, show it othervise
    function handleNoData() {
        name = $(".graph_identifier").attr("data-name");

        if (this.series.length > 0 && this.series[0].data.length > 0) {
            $('#message-'+name).fadeOut(250, function(){
                $('#container-'+name+', #table-'+name).fadeIn(250);
            });             
        } else {
            $('#container-'+name+', #table-'+name).fadeOut(250, function(){
                $('#message-'+name).fadeIn(250);
            });             
        }
    }

    // Add event listeners
    chartPrototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {
        H.addEvent(chart, 'load', handleNoData);
        H.addEvent(chart, 'redraw', handleNoData);
    });

}(Highcharts));
```

Problem is, that this code works **only** when you have **single** graph **per page**. But on my home page I have 5 different graphs and when one of them has no data, it hides all graphs.

I tried to modify the code and pass *chart* to `handleNoData` function like this:

```
H.addEvent(chart, 'load', handleNoData(chart));
H.addEvent(chart, 'load', printPage);
H.addEvent(chart, 'redraw', handleNoData(chart));
```

But then I just get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

I guess its because only thing you can do is to pass function name and not parameters (if you can, then I did not find out how in their API).

Right now I have to use this for every single graph, which is not what I want and also it does not detect redraws properly:

```
chart = $("#container").highcharts();
$(chart).on('load redraw', handleNoData(chart));
```

Does anybody have idea how to achieve this?

I spent really long time digging trough their API and Google, but I could not find anything.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I managed to find the problem and fix it. It was the graph identifier... Function itself worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to find the solution rather quickly, so I am posting fully working example:

```
<div id="container-graph_name" class="graph-container" data-name="graph_name"></div>
<div id="message-graph_name" class="message-container">No data to show</div>

<script>
    (function (H) {

        var chartPrototype = H.Chart.prototype;

        // Hide graph if there are no data, show it othervise
        function handleNoData() {
            var name = $(this.renderTo).attr("data-name");

            if (this.series.length > 0 && this.series[0].data.length > 0) {
                $('#message-'+name).fadeOut(250, function(){
                    $('#container-'+name+').fadeIn(250);
                });
            } else {
                $('#container-'+name+').fadeOut(250, function(){
                    $('#message-'+name).fadeIn(250);
                });
            }
        }

        // Add event listeners
        chartPrototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {
            H.addEvent(chart, 'load', handleNoData);
            H.addEvent(chart, 'redraw', handleNoData);
        });

    }(Highcharts));
</script>
```

It was indeed problem with identification of the chart itself. This code will take name of the chart from `data-name` attribute of container and use it to show/hide divs with ID's starting with `container-` and `message-` and ending with name that's set in `data-name` attribute.

Only thing you have to do, is to have every graph and message set up with their own unique ID as specified above.

Hope this helps somebody.